# Switch between 2 wifi connections in android

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

One connection is connected to a device that I need to download information from and another is connected to the internet. So I want to first connect to the wifi the device is on to download then I want to switch to a wifi with internet to upload.

Is there a way to switch between 2 different wifi connections in code in the app?

Comment: ?? Assuming IP, this should just happen.

Comment: Sure. [`WifiManager.enableNetwork()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)

Comment: Yeah but in my case both networks are active at the same time and in range. One will prioritize over the other.